# The font shorthand property is not working, but longhand properties do. Why?

Tags: html, css, fonts

Apologies for so simple a question, but it's been years since I've really had to play in CSS and this is eluding me, after a full day of testing. Thanks for any help.

The question is **shorthand vs longhand CSS declarations regarding font characteristics inheritence**. After much testing, I couldn't get Roboto (100, 300) to really work. One font-weight always overrode the other regardless of whether divs were nested or not. When written in shorthand Open Sans also failed, but worked fine using longhand for individual and nested div. What's going on? (*Combining font-family and font-size like: "font: 32px san-serif;" seems to be respected also*).

**This CSS formatting worked** for individual and nested divs, with the only changes being **Formal/Longhand** font, weight and color.

```
.div-1 {
    font: 32px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 300; 
    width: 800px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #333;serif
}
```

This **Shorthand** CSS formatting **failed** with **either or both weight or color included** in font declaration:

```
.div-1 {
    font: 32px #333 300 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    width: 800px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #333;serif
}
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title></title>

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Roboto' rel='stylesheet'>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="../test.css">

</head>
<body>

<div class="div-1">This is Div-1 text</div>
<div class="div-2">This is Div-2 text</div>
<div class="div-3">This is Div-3 text</div>

<div class="div-3">This is Div-3 text
<div class="div-1">This is Div-1 text</div>
<div class="div-2">This is Div-2 text</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you all for your amazingly quick responses - saved my bacon. It seems I made two mistakes in my coding. The response from buidingsramen below is correct and got me half-way there. The other issue seems to be that I MUST ask for specific font weights in the google fonts requests. I asked for Roboto, assuming I'd get the full family of weights - didn't work. Including the specific weight variants in the HTML (missed a comma and didn't catch it, which didn't help the cause!) did the job with the added help of removing the font color and putting the weight first.

Answer (score 4):

There's two separate problems here:

- Color is not a part of the `font` shorthand.
- Font-weight must come before font-size.

Should work if you fix that.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the correct syntax for `font` shorthand.  See the [mdn documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font#Syntax) for examples of correctly formatted shorthand rules.

```css
.div-1 {
    font: bolder 32px 'Open Sans', sans-serif; 
    color: #333;
    width: 800px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-1">This is Div-1 text</div>
<div class="div-2">This is Div-2 text</div>
<div class="div-3">This is Div-3 text</div>

<div class="div-3">This is Div-3 text</div>
<div class="div-1">This is Div-1 text</div>
<div class="div-2">This is Div-2 text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**These are the acceptable properties of the `font` shorthand:**

(Note that `color` is not on the list.)

- `font-style`
- `font-variant`
- `font-weight`
- `font-size`
- `line-height`
- `font-family`

**Here's the permissible order of properties:**

First (in any order):

- `font-style` and/or `font-variant` and/or `font-weight` or nothing

Second:

- `font-size`

Third:

- `line-height` or nothing

Fourth:

- `font-family`

Fifth:

- other less popular properties (see link below)

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/fonts.html#font-shorthand